# How to change httpd.conf to allow large file upload

Tags: apache, file-upload, httpd.conf

I have a web application built with Django. It requires users to upload 
a file. But however when I make a deployment in final production
I got this error message:

[image]

What directive I should use to change the HTTPD.CONF?

Currently mine looks like this:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /u33/app/www/foobar/run

<VirtualHost *:8061>

    ServerAdmin coolguy@cool_univ.ac.id
    DocumentRoot /u33/app/www/foobar/html
    ServerName foo.ac.co.id
    ErrorLog logs/foobar-error_log
    CustomLog logs/foobar-access_log common
    ErrorLog /u33/app/www/foobar/logs/error_log
    ServerAlias foobar.com

    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip

    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/
    #RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]

    Alias /static/ /u33/app/www/foobar/html/

    RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example1$
    RewriteRule ^(.+) http://cool_univ.ac.id/foobar/#/148/target-predictions [NE,R=302]

    <Directory "/u33/app/www/foobar/html/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/u33/app/www/foobar/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        #Options None
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>



    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIDaemonProcess foobar.com python-path=/u33/app/www/foobar/wsgi-scripts:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/u21/ewijaya/.anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup foobar.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /u33/app/www/foobar/wsgi-scripts/webframework/wsgi.py process-group=foobar.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: 2 years later did you find a way?

Answer (score 2):

Though not mentioned in your `httpd.conf`, I assume you are using SSL, as the error message implies (port 443). In this case, add a [SSLRenegBufferSize](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrenegbuffersize) directive with the maximum expected file size in bytes, see [Request Entity Too Large error while uploading files of more than 128KB over SSL](https://serverfault.com/questions/419723) on Server Fault.